# Как поделить два значения select count? (PostrgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Есть таблица, в ней есть поля с нулевыми значениями и с валидными, требуется найти соотношение.

Пытаюсь делать так

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM test1 
 WHERE test_id IS NOT NULL 
/ 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test1
```

Не работает, выдавая ошибку синтаксиса. Есть ли какие-то способы использовать арифметические операции между двумя select-ами?

Comment: @Viktorov Вы не учли, когда таблица пустая. Там 0 / 0 будет

Comment: @ZaArs не вижу смысла обрабатывать эту ошибку внутри запроса. Будет и будет, такое надо обрабатывать там, откуда этот запрос вызывается

Answer (score 2):

Если хочется именно арифметическую операцию между двумя запросами, то можно так:

```
select (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test1 WHERE test_id IS NOT NULL) /
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test1)
```

Но более разумно можно сделать так:

```
select count(test_id)/count(1) from test1
```

`count(test_id)` посчитает только те значения, в которых `test_id is not null`. Таким образом вы обратитесь к таблице только 1 раз

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test1) FROM test1 WHERE test_id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Если надо примерное соотношение числа NULL записей - то оно есть в статистике планировщика:

```
select null_fraq from pg_stats where tablename = ? and attname = ?
```

Быстро, неточно.

```
select (count(*) filter(where test_id is null))::float / count(*)::float from tablename;
```

`seqscan` таблицы и актуальное для этого MVCC снимка соотношение. Обратите внимание на приведение к float. Деление одного bigint на другой bigint (count возвращает только bigint) даст абсолютно правильный неверный результат.

```
melkij=> create temp table foo (i int);
CREATE TABLE
melkij=> insert into foo select generate_series(1,1000);
INSERT 0 1000
melkij=> insert into foo select null from  generate_series(1,100);
INSERT 0 100
melkij=> select (count(*) filter(where i is null))::float / count(*)::float from foo;
      ?column?      
--------------------
 0.0909090909090909
(1 строка)

melkij=> select (count(*) filter(where i is null)) / count(*) from foo;
 ?column? 
----------
        0
(1 строка)
```